# Add TensorBoard to application

Tags: python, tensorboard

I would like to know how to add metrics like accuracy,precision and save model  to this tensorboard logistic regression:

```
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import fashion_mnist
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split
import tensorflow as tf

(x_train, y_train), (x_test, y_test) = fashion_mnist.load_data()
x_train, x_test = x_train/255., x_test/255.

x_train, x_val, y_train, y_val = train_test_split(x_train, y_train, test_size=0.15)
x_train = tf.reshape(x_train, shape=(-1, 784))
x_test  = tf.reshape(x_test, shape=(-1, 784))

weights = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(784, 10), dtype=tf.float64))
biases  = tf.Variable(tf.random.normal(shape=(10,), dtype=tf.float64))

def logistic_regression(x):
    lr = tf.add(tf.matmul(x, weights), biases)
    #return tf.nn.sigmoid(lr)
    return lr


def cross_entropy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.one_hot(y_true, 10)
    loss = tf.nn.softmax_cross_entropy_with_logits(labels=y_true, logits=y_pred)
    return tf.reduce_mean(loss)

def accuracy(y_true, y_pred):
    y_true = tf.cast(y_true, dtype=tf.int32)
    preds = tf.cast(tf.argmax(y_pred, axis=1), dtype=tf.int32)
    preds = tf.equal(y_true, preds)
    return tf.reduce_mean(tf.cast(preds, dtype=tf.float32))

def grad(x, y):
    with tf.GradientTape() as tape:
        y_pred = logistic_regression(x)
        loss_val = cross_entropy(y, y_pred)
    return tape.gradient(loss_val, [weights, biases])

n_batches = 10000
learning_rate = 0.01
batch_size = 128

dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((x_train, y_train))
dataset = dataset.repeat().shuffle(x_train.shape[0]).batch(batch_size)

optimizer = tf.optimizers.SGD(learning_rate)

for batch_numb, (batch_xs, batch_ys) in enumerate(dataset.take(n_batches), 1):
    gradients = grad(batch_xs, batch_ys)
    optimizer.apply_gradients(zip(gradients, [weights, biases]))

    y_pred = logistic_regression(batch_xs)
    loss = cross_entropy(batch_ys, y_pred)
    acc = accuracy(batch_ys, y_pred)
    print("Batch number: %i, loss: %f, accuracy: %f" % (batch_numb, loss, acc))
```

i'm new to tensor and I only got write logs in tensorflow 1.x
When `with tf.Session as sess` left from tensorflow i get lost 
in the other ways of making code.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your code will look something like this using simple Tensorflow V2:

Start with the model creation, Logistic regression can be seen as a single layer perceptron with sigmoid activation so we will add an input layer with as many inputs as features and one output layer with sigmoid activation per each output class.

```
input = tf.keras.Input(shape=(nfeatures))
output = tf.keras.layers.Dense(nclasses,activation='sigmoid')(input)

model = tf.keras.Model(inputs=input,outputs=output,name='MyLinearRegression')
```

Than we create the optimizer and the loss function:

```
opt = tf.keras.optimizers.Adadelta()
lss = tf.keras.losses.categorical_crossentropy
met = tf.keras.metrics.Accuracy()
```

You have to use categorica_crossentropy or sparse_categorical_crossentropy depending on the labels (hot encoded or not). For this loss you may want to change the activation to softmax.

Now we can "compile" the model this way:

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss=lss,metrics=met)
model.summary()
```

So now we can create the TensorBoard callback:

```
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir,write_graph=True,update_freq='batch')
```

And than train like this:

```
model.fit(train,epochs=100,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback],validation_data = val)
```

If your dataset is a numpy dataset you can create a TF dataset like this:

```
dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,labels))

train = dataset.take(train_size)
test = dataset.skip(train_size).batch(batchsize)
val = test.skip(test_size).batch(batchsize)
test = test.take(test_size).batch(batchsize)
```

Where train is your train dataset, val the validation one and test the test dataset.

Comment: so, you say that my optimizer should be `tf.nn.softmax` and my loss  `tf.keras.losses.CategoricalCrossentropy` because I have my features one-hotted.? Is Adadelta a better optimizier?

Comment: Your optimize will be for example Adadelta while your loss will be CategoricalCrossentropy for the one-hotted values. I usually use Adadelta when I first try models because it has a "self optimizing" learning rate but I've noticed that in the first phases of the training it's very aggressive with the lr.

Comment: If I run this code till model.fit, I got an error : `Type of 'metrics' argument not understood. Expected a list or dictionary,`. I set a dummy nfeatures, and nclasses

Comment: That's because you have to pass a list of metrics even if you have just one, so you can change in model.compile metrics = [met]

Comment: Are you god @Edo98 ? You sve my life, model is running ok

Answer (score 1):

First of all you have to create a callback function to update Tensorboard:

```
tensorboard_callback = tf.keras.callbacks.TensorBoard(log_dir=logdir,write_graph=True,update_freq='batch')
```

Where logdir is a string to an existing directory.

than you can compile your model like this:

```
model.compile(optimizer=opt,loss=lss,metrics=met)
```

Where obviously opt is your optimizer, lss your loss function and optionally met your metrics.

Now you can train the model like this:

```
model.fit(train,epochs=100,callbacks=[tensorboard_callback],validation_data = val)
```

It will create a Tensorboard instance and you will see the address in the terminal. You can copy the link in your browser and see it.

I see that you are still using the "old" Tensorflow v1 way of compiling and creating the model. Using model.compile and model.fit is easyer and faster (in my opinion) if you aren't using particoular training methods. (You can't greate GANs this way for example).

Comment: i am too noob for this, what should I put in callbacks? How is the code reestructured? This is an simple multi class logistic regression